# ¿Como puedo añadir mas de un valor a una varible en un select?- SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

**CODIGO**

```
declare @prueba varchar(50)
 set @prueba= (select top 2 cod_ven from VENDEDOR WHERE ruc_ven in('001','002','003') and cod_Ven not like 'M%' and cod_ven !='55')

 select @prueba,acodigo,adescri 
 from MAEART m 
 where  ACODIGO like '10%'  or acodigo not like '%M' 
and acodigo like '20%' or acodigo like '30%' or acodigo like '50%' and aestado='V'
```

Como se puede ver en la imagen, estoy llevando mas de un dato a esa variable, soy consiente de ello, pero quisiera alguna otra alternativa para añadir esos dos datos a una columna dentro de ese select.

Estoy agregando el código de dos vendedores a esos productos, por lo cual, el código se va a repetir varias veces de los vendedores, y de los 659 productos se repetirá dos veces, ya que va en relación a los vendedores, quisiera una ayuda en este caso por favor.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo intente ingresar de manera directa pero los filtros que se aprecian dejan de funcionar y me arrojan todos los vendedores.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les agradeciria mucho su ayuda, acotare que entre ambas tablas no ay ningun campo en compu como para agruparlo

Comment: Como sugerencia: el código va como texto. La gente aca usualmente trata de replicar y trabajar sobre el código que usas, así que con imagenes es mucho más dispendioso (y se pueden omitir errores que tú tengas). Igual va con los mensajes de error y, en lo posible, con los daots de prueba. Haz de cuenta que nosotros te respondamos con imagenes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para tener más de un valor en una variable, es necesario declarar la variable como tabla. No existen las matrices en SQL Server, por lo que no puedes asignar más de un valor a una variable escalar.

El código quedaría algo similar a esto. Acomodé un poco tu condición pero no sé si lo haya hecho de la forma adecuada.

```
DECLARE @prueba TABLE( 
    cod_ven varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO @prueba 
SELECT TOP 2 cod_ven 
FROM VENDEDOR 
WHERE ruc_ven in('001','002','003') 
AND cod_Ven not like 'M%' 
AND cod_ven !='55';

 SELECT p.cod_ven, 
        m.acodigo,
        m.adescri 
 FROM MAEART m 
 CROSS
 JOIN @prueba p
 WHERE  (ACODIGO like '10%'  or acodigo not like '%M' )
 AND (acodigo LIKE '20%' 
    OR acodigo LIKE '30%' 
    OR acodigo LIKE '50%') 
 AND aestado='V';
```

Comment: muchas gracias, eres lo maximo, waaaaa